# Back up Mac Server with Time Machine Server installed on the same Time Machine Server

Tags: macos, backup, time-machine

I want to back up several Workstations (“Workstations 1-4” in diagram below) and a Mac OS X Server (“MacMini Server” in diagram below) that runs “Time Machine Server” on that same “Time Machine Server.”

Is this possible?

The MacMini server doesn’t seem to find the “Time Machine Server” for backups. I read that this is due to the fact that Time Machine backups via network are organized in another way than “normal” Time Machine backups are.

//EDIT

MacOS server is running MacOS 10.8.5 with server app v2.2.1(169)-
workstations are running 10.10.1, 10.9.5 and 10.8.4

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The way to do this is to have the server back up via normal local-disk Time Machine.

"Time Machine Server" is just AFP file service. Time Machine client machines mount a shared folder/volume of your completely normal traditional AFP file server, and each machine makes a disk image file on it (technically it's a "sparsebundle" disk image which is actually a bunch of equal-size files in a folder, but that's not important to this discussion; it looks and acts like any disk image file).

The AFP client and server have protections to make sure a machine can never use its AFP client to mount one of its own AFP server shares. Otherwise bad things would happen, especially if anyone started trying to copy files onto themselves (one view of the files being the local disk, the other view being the AFP mounted share). So, since Time Machine over the network uses AFP, a machine cannot do a network-style Time Machine backup to itself.

Just give the server a local disk to do normal local-disk-style Time Machine backups to.

Comment: So the only way to back up the data from all machines to both disks is to split them? One part local Server-TM-backup and one part Workstation-TM-backup via TM-Server? (They are mirrored)

Comment: 10.8 had support for selecting multiple backup targets, so you should be able to configure the server computer to back itself up to *both* external HDDs (result: it'll alternate backing up to them). If the Time Machine service is configured to store backups on the server's internal disk, they'll get copied to the externals along with everything else.

Comment: I don't remember if Server v2.2.1 had support for serving multiple backup folders or if that was added in a later version. If it did, it might be better to serve a backup folder on each external HDD, and configure the clients to back up to both of them.